# When to create a custom Classloaders?

Tags: java, classloader

Why would you ever need to create a custom Classloaders? A real world example would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application servers such as Java EE servers and OSGI containers use custom classloader to support updating and removing software dynamically.

Other custom classloaders are used to support dynamic code injections (From Java 5.0 Instrumentation is preferred)

Comment: Other custom classloaders are used to support dynamic code injections" Is it sort of like dependency injection containers?

Comment: They alter the code at runtime, even altering system classes.

Answer (score 4):

Typical cases are:

- Instrument/Load classes at runtime.
- Load encrypted classes.
- Remote class loading.

Answer (score 2):

It's not something you'd be likely to ever have to write yourself, but you might make use of one as part of some complex frameworks -- for instance, dependency injection is often implemented with ClassLoaders. Another common use of custom class loaders is in unit testing: a custom class loader can be used to replace classes loaded by the unit under test with "dummy" versions which respond in a controllable way (for instance, to simulate errors which would otherwise be difficult to create).

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking it is really hard to imagine Java ecosystem without non-standard classloaders. A lot of loosely coupled architectures are based on classloaders. I would suggest to spend several hours with JSPF (Java Simple Plugin Framework), because only some practical experience will be really valuable for you. JSPF is quite simple and allows not only to understand potential cases, when custom classloaders are needed, but also to feel the power of such solution.

Try to follow a simple plan:

- Define an interface (a contract)
- Provide an implementation as independent module/jar
- Use JSPF and previously defined contract to discover available implementation(s)
- Do some useful stuff with discovered implementation
- Understand you have loosely coupled system
- Find out how classloaders are actually used in this example

Please also look through the following links:

- http://code.google.com/p/jspf/
- http://code.google.com/p/jspf/wiki/UsageGuide